# How to generically test if mediaqueries are supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

May sound odd, but I'm looking for a simple way to test if `any` mediaqueries are supported on a browser.

I know there is [respondjs](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), which comes with a [window.matchMedia](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/respond.src.js#L4) polyfill, but even using it, I still have to query specific queries like:

```
  window.matchMedia("all and (min-width: 400px"));
```

which returns an `obj.matches = true/false`.

What I'm looking for is a generic way to test, "if mediaQueries are supported", yes or no.

I'm currently using:

```
  window.matchMedia("screen and (orienation:landscape),
                      screen and (orientation:portrait)");
```

but I don't really like this way of testing.

I also tried:

```
  window.matchMedia("all");
```

but this (of course) returns `true` in IE8 when using the `matchMedia` polyfill. Also, I can't test for `matchMedia` itself, because I would miss out on a lot of browsers that support media queries, but not `window.matchMedia` ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia)).

**Question:**
Is there a nice and simple way to test for media query support? If possible, I would not want to use `window.matchMedia` at all to do that.

**EDIT:**
I also checked [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js), which also tests for a specific mediaQuery condition (**mq**):

```
testMediaQuery = function( mq ) {

  var matchMedia = window.matchMedia || window.msMatchMedia;
  if ( matchMedia ) {
    return matchMedia(mq).matches;
  }

  var bool;

  injectElementWithStyles('@media ' + mq + ' { #' + mod + ' { position: absolute; } }', function( node ) {
    bool = (window.getComputedStyle ?
              getComputedStyle(node, null) :
              node.currentStyle)['position'] == 'absolute';
  });

  return bool;

 },
```

So no generic test, if mediaQueries are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can choose this option in modernizr

http://modernizr.com/download/

Comment: see my comment above. It also tests for specific conditions, aka `testMediaQuery("all and (orientation:landscape)")`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly 2k me a second to grasp that, too ;-)